# Can not get vim to work like i want

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme, vim-airline, powerline

I have tried fixing vim to my likings but I alawys encountered a lot of problems due to my lack of knowldege.The most commons ones are:

Powerline font not rendering properly example [here](https://ibb.co/dwxzGH)

Syntax Highlighting not giving the expected color

Background color not being rendered properly
I am aiming for a result which would look pretty similiar to [this](http://ibb.co/cXOgwH) when I currently have [this](http://ibb.co/dBviAc).
If the information given is not enough I will give you additional information in the comments. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking 2 questions:

- How do you get fancy font characters for *line plugins?
- Where are my syntax highlighting colors?

#### Fancy font patching

You will need to refer to your status line plugin for how it wants you to patch a font and setup your terminal. [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) for example has instructions on how to do this.

#### Syntax highlighting colors

You need to make sure you have the following lines in your `vimrc` file:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

This will turn on syntax highlighting and filetype specific plugins (aka ftplugins). As long as you have a color terminal and `$TERM` is set correctly then the colors should show.

Make sure you also specify a colorscheme via `:colorscheme` in your `vimrc` file as well:

```
colorscheme nord
```

It should also be noted that [nord](https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord-vim) colorscheme *requires* you to update your terminal's theme as well in order to work properly.

Comment: No no, syntax highlighting actually does work but with diffrent colors...so it works but not like it is supposed to...so i do have those lines on my vimrc but I have commented them out cause they do not work right...I also have the colorscheme line which activates my theme but the problem isn't that it doesnt activate but it just doesnt render or work properly, u understand me?

Comment: I just want to mention I even tried to delete all my vim config which includes .vim and .vimrc and using some from some repos in github with xfce4-terminal and gnome-terminal and none of them seem to work properly